# Функция map Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть задача:

Создать функцию from_hex_to_rgb, которая принимает на вход строку - закодированный код цвета в формате RGB и возвращает кортеж из трех значений (оттенок_красного, оттенок_зеленого, оттенок_синего).

Вот посмотрите примеры:

```
from_hex_to_rgb(#000000) => (0, 0, 0)
from_hex_to_rgb(#FFFFFF) => (255, 255, 255)
from_hex_to_rgb(#FF0000) => (255,0, 0)
from_hex_to_rgb(#00FF00) => (0,255, 0)
from_hex_to_rgb(#0000FF) => (0,0,255)
from_hex_to_rgb(#FFFFFF) => (255,255,255)
from_hex_to_rgb(#87CEEB) => (135,206,235)
from_hex_to_rgb(#87CEFA) => (135,206,250)
from_hex_to_rgb(#191970) => (25,25,112)
```

Как только функция будет готова, ее необходимо применить ко всем элементам списка colors при помощи функции map. Ниже уже имеется готовый список colors и цикл обхода результата функции map. Добавьте только название функции внутри вызова map

Вот шаблон кода

```
def from_hex_to_rgb(color: str) -> tuple:
    pass


colors = ['#B22222', '#DC143C', '#FF0000', '#FF6347', '#FF7F50', '#CD5C5C', '#F08080', '#E9967A',
          '#FA8072', '#FFA07A', '#FF4500', '#FF8C00', '#FFA500', '#FFD700', '#B8860B', '#DAA520',
          '#EEE8AA', '#BDB76B', '#F0E68C', '#808000', '#FFFF00', '#9ACD32', '#556B2F', '#6B8E23',
          '#7CFC00', '#7FFF00', '#ADFF2F']

for red, green, blue in map(..., colors):
    print(f"Red={red}, Green={green}, Blue={blue}")
```

Вот мой код РЕШЕНИЕ:

```
def from_hex_to_rgb(color: str) -> tuple:
    red = int(color[1:2], 16)
    green = int(color[2:3], 16)
    blue = int(color[1:2], 16)
    return red, green, blue


colors = ['#B22222', '#DC143C', '#FF0000', '#FF6347', '#FF7F50', '#CD5C5C', '#F08080', '#E9967A',
          '#FA8072', '#FFA07A', '#FF4500', '#FF8C00', '#FFA500', '#FFD700', '#B8860B', '#DAA520',
          '#EEE8AA', '#BDB76B', '#F0E68C', '#808000', '#FFFF00', '#9ACD32', '#556B2F', '#6B8E23',
          '#7CFC00', '#7FFF00', '#ADFF2F']

for red, green, blue in map(from_hex_to_rgb, colors):
    print(f"Red={red}, Green={green}, Blue={blue}")
```

Но решение не правильное. КАК сделать правильно?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас функция неправильно вытаскивала цифры из hex rgb. Например, для `"#123456"` ваша функция вытащила бы `print(color[1:2], color[2:3], color[1:2])`: `1 2 1`, а не `12 34 56`

Попробуйте так:

```
def from_hex_to_rgb(color: str) -> tuple:
    red = int(color[1:3], 16)
    green = int(color[3:5], 16)
    blue = int(color[5:7], 16)
    return red, green, blue
```